# Share embedded video on facebook with inline play

Tags: facebook, video

I have a page that has an iframe for playing video. When someone shares the link on Facebook, I would like it to play inline on their wall.

I have tried quite a variety of facebook tags and nothing seems to work. When you share the link, you get the image with the playback overlay, but when you click it nothing happens. When I right click on the image, it shows 'Movie not loaded...'

Here is my source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Proposal</title>

<meta name="description" content="A mograph marriage proposal. Awesome!&nbsp; With some great animated typography. Congrats Adam Rosenbaum!" />

<meta property="og:title" content="Proposal" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://laurafolco.com/video/video.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://laurafolco.com/video/Proposal.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A mograph marriage proposal. Awesome!&nbsp; With some great animated typography. Congrats Adam Rosenbaum!" />
<meta property="og:video" content="https://player.vimeo.com/video/98891632?portrait=0" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="700" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="394" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />

</head>

<body>

<p>A mograph marriage proposal. Awesome!&nbsp; Congrats <a href="https://vimeo.com/user3254596" rel="author">Adam Rosenbaum</a>!</p>
<div class="media_embed"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/98891632?portrait=0" frameborder="0" width="700" height="394"></iframe></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h4>Author Notes</h4>
<p>On 6.21.14 I showed this to my girlfriend. She said yes.</p>
<p>Music: Devotchka</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The URL is http://laurafolco.com/video/video.html

Is it possible to share the above link, and have the video play inline? or would the user need to share the actual video link?

Comment: Does it help if you define og:video:secure_url

Comment: nope, that didn't work :\

Comment: When I go to https://player.vimeo.com/video/98891632?portrait=0 it is a html player but you say it is flash. I think it have to be flash

Comment: That's the thing I'm trying to figure out. I can't tell from the vimeo player what the actual file name is. Any ideas on getting that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that I need to specify the Vimeo flash URL first, like this:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=98891632" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="700" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="394" />

<meta property="og:video" content="https://player.vimeo.com/video/98891632?portrait=0" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="700" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="394" />
```

Vimeo says that their flash API is deprecated, but it seems to work.